# 'UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height' app extension workaround causing view UI issues

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I need to get the status bar and navigation bar heights in my custom iOS share extension, in order to position my `topHeaderView` and a `shareMessageTableView` right below it. Since *shared* in `UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height` is not available for app extensions, I had to use the workaround provided [here](https://medium.com/@lucabecchetti/calculate-top-distance-status-bar-height-and-navigation-bar-height-of-uiviewcontroller-without-e4dbfe241a77).

```
/// Calculate top distance with "navigationBar" and "statusBar" by adding a
/// subview constraint to navigationBar or to topAnchor or superview
/// - Returns: The real distance between topViewController and Bottom navigationBar
func calculateTopDistance() -> CGFloat {

    /// Create view to measure
    let measureView: UIView = UIView()
    measureView.backgroundColor = .clear
    view.addSubview(measureView)

    /// Add needed constraints
    measureView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    measureView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    measureView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    measureView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    if let nav = navigationController {
        measureView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nav.navigationBar.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    } else {
        measureView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    /// Force layout
    view.layoutIfNeeded()

    /// Calculate distance
    let distance = view.frame.size.height - measureView.frame.size.height

    /// Remove from superview
    measureView.removeFromSuperview()

    return distance
}
```

I called this function in `viewDidAppear()` of the main view controller (calling it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` will crash the extension instead):

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // Adjust top header view to accommodate iPhone X's notch.
    topHeaderView.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 50 + self.calculateTopDistance())
    shareMessageTableView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: topHeaderView.frame.height)
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        shareMessageTableView.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height - topHeaderView.frame.height - self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
    } else {
        shareMessageTableView.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height - topHeaderView.frame.height)
    }
}
```

Then I have a 2nd view controller (photo preview screen) that I pushed programmatically using `.instantiateViewController` and `.pushViewController`, not with segue in IB. In this controller, I set up a keyboard notification that will call these functions to adjust the view -- so that I can fit the keyboard while still showing the whole image:

```
/// Delegate function when keyboard will show.
///
/// - Parameter notification: Notification
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    keyboardIsVisible = true
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        self.keyboardSize = keyboardSize
        adjustViews()
    }
}

func adjustViews() {
    if self.keyboardIsVisible && self.keyboardSize != nil {
        self.view.frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - self.keyboardSize!.height
    } else {
        self.view.frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    }
}
```

So this is working as intended, **up until I start changing orientation.** Once the orientation changes (doesn't matter from where to where), the view will not adjust anymore to show the whole image even though `adjustViews()` is still being called. Instead, the keyboard will come up and cover part of the image. This problem started happening when I implemented the `calculateTopDistance()` function on top, so I need help and suggestions on how to fix this function. I don't know of any other workarounds so this is the best one for me so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found a workaround to my issue. Instead of adjusting the whole view, I just adjust the bottom constraint of the scrollview (that contains the imageview) to the height of the keyboard. Done!